# Using id as bookmarks does not work in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I am now making a website that using id as bookmarks such that user can go to the certain paragraph when clicking the particular links.

e.g.
When a user clicks www.abc.com#my-paragraph

the user will go to

```
<p id="my-paragraph">hello</p>
```

in the website

That works in all browser except IE. How to fix the problem? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure your IDs are unique and it's not jumping somewhere else?  Are you using JQuery/Javascript/Etc to find them?  Internal-page anchors/bookmarks have been around for a long time.  They should be supported back to archaic browsers of all flavors.

Comment: I've seen from the reply that you've figured out by yourself. I suggest that you could write your result as a reply and mark your solution as answer if it solved your problem. And this will be helpful for someone meets with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

if your paragraph is `<p id="my-paragraph">hello</p>` then you will need to add:

`<a href="#my-paragraph"> The Website </a>`

to a button in html.

Comment: He said it works in other browsers though.  Internal page anchors/bookmarks have been around since forever and it's standardized at this point unless he's using something like JS/Jquery instead of built-in browser functionality.  I tested IE7 and they work fine.

Comment: I have figured out the reason why finally. Because there is a "name" attribute in the link. e.g. <a name="#my-paragraph" href="#my-paragraph">, the bookmark does not work

Comment: Did you have `name` instead of `id`, that could have been the reason. Glad it worked out.